# Fetching data using NHibernate with Automapper

Tags: c#, nhibernate, automapper

In my selling process I use automapper to map Cart entity into CartModel.
Cart entity containts Currency entity witch should be mapped into CurrencyCode string. And I have a question, should be that Currency entity explicitly fetched by nHibernate on repository method or this is OK, when I leave that in my mapping rules ? 
What is the best solution ?

Honestly, I think that automapper shouldn't send query into database, I'm right ?

Mapping:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Cart, CartModel>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Amount, src => src.MapFrom(s => s.ArticleList.Count))
   .ForMember(dest => dest.CurrencyCode, src => src.MapFrom(s => s.Currency.Code))
   .ForMember(dest => dest.CartLines, src => src.MapFrom(s => s.ArticleList));
```

CartService:

```
public virtual CartModel GetCartInfo(long cartId)
{
  var dto = new CartModel();
  var cart = _cartRepository.GetForCartSummary(cartId);
  Mapper.Map(cart, dto);

 return dto;
}
```

CartRepository:

```
 public Cart GetForCartSummary(long cartId)
 {
    return Session.Query<Cart>()
               .Where(c => c.Id == cartId)
             //  .Fetch(c => c.Currency)
               .FetchMany(c => c.ArticleList)
               .Single();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should actually depend on how you setup your nhibernate mapping for Cart.
If Currency is not mapped as lazy loaded, the mapper will not force nhibernate to query the database again.
If you map (I mean nhibernate mapping, not automapper) your entity correctly, nhibernate will try to retrieve the object (and all dependencies) in one query.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have lazy load enabled in nHibernate, so data is fetched when automapper is invoked. But is that OK, that automapper runs query ?

Comment: It depends, if you always use automapper to map the object and child objects, then it does not make any sense to lazy load it...
As I said, define it as not lazy, otherwise you'll simply run too many queries to retrieve your objects...
Or, if you don't need the child properties which invoke new queries, do not automap them...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest loading directly from your query into your dto object.  it will avoid these types of problems.

so your query would look something like this

return (from c in Session.Query()
where c.Id == cartId
select new CartModel { Amount = c.ArticleList.Count, CurrencyCode = c.Currency.Code, CartLines = c.ArticleList}).Single();

I'm guessing that ArticleList is a collection mapped to the Cart object.  I would add the a BatchSize to that mapping so you are fetching the sub items 1 at a time.

Comment: Do you think that using nhibernate lazy loading is generally a bad practice when ftlatting entity properties into dto ?

Comment: I wouldn't say that.  When I'm developing with NHibernate I live to log all my SQL statements to see what NHibernate is doing under the covers.  That tells me if I need to change my mappings to add Fetch's or BatchSizes.